# Occasional exception writing compressed content via WebApi to the client in streamed transfer mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, invalidoperationexception

We have a WEPAPI service, which writes data in compressed form to the client using a message handler. Since we occasional receive very large messages, the system is configured using

```
HttpSelfHostConfiguration.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
```

The compress logic is:

```
public class CompressedHttpContent : CompressionHttpContent
{
    public CompressedHttpContent(HttpContent content, ICompressor compressor)
        : base(content, compressor)
    {
    }

    protected async override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.TransportContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.OriginalContent != null)
                using (OriginalContent)
                {
                    using (var contentStream = await OriginalContent.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    {
                        var compressedStream = Compressor.CreateCompressionStream(stream);
                        await contentStream.CopyToAsync(compressedStream);
                        compressedStream.Close();
                        compressedStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And occasionally we get an exception like:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The AsyncEventArgs implementation 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream+WriteAsyncState' tried to set the state to Pending multiple times without completing a pending operation. This could be caused by an incorrect application AsyncEventArgs implementation or other extensibility code that invokes Set() multiple times.
Server stack trace:
at System.Runtime.AsyncEventArgs.set_State(OperationState value)
at System.Runtime.AsyncEventArgs.SetAsyncState(AsyncEventArgsCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Runtime.AsyncEventArgs`1.Set(AsyncEventArgsCallback callback, TArgument arguments, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedOutputAsyncStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteDeflaterOutput(Boolean isAsync)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean isAsync)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_1(Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at CompressedHttpContent.<SerializeToStreamAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Unfortunately, when I search for this error, I don't get any hits.

We didn't get this when we were using the buffered transfer mode. We could potentially change to StreamedRequest mode, as it's only the incoming requests which can be very large.

Has anyone seen this or have any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When experimenting with compressed responses, I encountered the same error.
What I found interesting was the following bit from the source code of BufferedOutputAsyncStream, which appears in the call stack:
"  BufferedOutputAsyncStream is not a general-purpose stream wrapper, it requires that the base stream
     1. allow concurrent IO (for multiple BeginWrite calls)
     2. support the BeginWrite,BeginWrite,BeginWrite,.. Close() calling pattern.

Currently BufferedOutputAsyncStream only used to wrap the System.Net.HttpResponseStream, which satisfy both requirements."
(https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/BufferedOutputAsyncStream.cs)

This requirement does not appear to be fulfilled for the GZipStream, as can be tested with some simple code (generally throws an exception).

```
byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(@"largerfile");
GZipStream gzs = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
gzs.WriteAsync(ba,0, 200000);
gzs.WriteAsync(ba, 0, 200000);
```

I suspect that ASP.NET WebAPI may be calling the GZipStream in an unsupported manner - although I am not yet convinced that this is actually what's happening.